# Execute command on Terminal launch (macOS)

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there an easy way to force the Terminal to run a command every time it is launched on macOS?

I did some searching on here and most of the time this question is asked on here with regards to Ubuntu but I can't find a Mac solution. For Ubuntu, everyone says to use `bashrc` but that file isn't in my home directory.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most common way is to add the command to `.bash_profile` file in your home directory.

Quoting `man bash` which lists other options as well:

> When  bash  is  invoked  as  an  interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`,  if  that  file exists.   After  reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is  readable.

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked. However, I found it strange that I didn't have a `.bash_profile` in my home directory. I created it, added the command on there and restarted Terminal and voila!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a command when Terminal.app opens a shell, not just for any interactive shell:

1. Open **Terminal** → **Preferences** → **Profiles**.
2. Select the profile you use, then switch to the **Shell** tab.
3. Under **Startup**, enter the command you wish to run as the **Run command**.

   [image]